# How can I measure, that how much data of internet I used on MAC for a certain period of time?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-appstore, internet

I'm using Mac Book Pro. For internet I use modem. My question, Is there any way to find out how many data (in GB) I have already used for a certain period of time (in 30 days).
Or It will count the amount of data I'll use in coming month or something? Is there any apps to measure it? I'm talking about used data. Not bandwidth. If anyone knows, please share it with me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the activity monitor thats built in to OS X? Use spot light to find/open activity monitor and click on the network button near the bottom and it will display the data sent and received since the last restart.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But I want to see the use of long period. Without restart machine. How could I do that? :(

Comment: There are lots apps, just google "measure data usage in mac os x". I recommended activity monitor cause its free and already installed on your mac. Instead on a restart just record what your stats are at the beginning of your test and deduct them at the end, say in a week.